# Is there CHM file available for VS 2010 documentation?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, documentation

I have VS 2010 ultimate edition and the documentation (VS + framework classes documention) that comes along with it is in the form of HTML pages and uses in-built web server. So, whenever I need to see a topic, it starts the webserver and loads default help page, wherein I type for help topic and then it gives me that page.

I was wondering if there is CHM format help available for VS 2010 (.Net Framework 4.0) documentation? It is more convenient & speedy to use CHM than HTML documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can create it using [this](http://packagethis.codeplex.com/) project

Comment: I tried using packagethis from codeplex, but it uses MSDN content service to get the content. My bandwidth is low and I already have HTML offline help content. Moreover the tool looks a bit heavy on memory usage and when I select a parent topic checkbox, its child topics checkboxes don't get automatically selected.

Comment: What exactly you need from the MSDN?

Comment: Please see my main question. I need VS 2010 (+ .net framework 4.0) CHM help (documentation) file.

Comment: You need to ask from somebody with a good internet to do the job for you (I don't have time...) - You may look http://www.softany.com/winchm/